# Dynamic JOIN of multiple tables in SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, union-all

I am creating a procedure in `Bigquery` to generate a table with the union of data from several tables.
The total number of tables is stored in an array that can vary in content.

This is an example of what I have:

```
DECLARE dataset STRING DEFAULT "MY_DATASET";
DECLARE tablesArray ARRAY<STRING>;

SET tablesArray = ['TABLE_ONE','TABLE_TWO']
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MY_DATASET.TABLE_TWO
```

How can you build this into a procedure efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dynamic SQL in BigQuery script.

- [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate)

```sql
DECLARE dataset STRING DEFAULT "MY_DATASET";
DECLARE tablesArray ARRAY<STRING>;

SET tablesArray = ['TABLE_ONE','TABLE_TWO'];

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT STRING_AGG('SELECT * FROM `MY_DATASET.'|| t || '`', '\n UNION ALL\n')
    FROM UNNEST(tablesArray) t
);
```

> SELECT * FROM `MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE`
> UNION ALL
> SELECT * FROM `MY_DATASET.TABLE_TWO`

Comment: If all of your table are stored in same dataset and have same schema,  you might consider  using wild card table instead of union-ing all the tables.  see  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables